# What's the difference between an C# Interface and an Objective-C Protocol?

Tags: c#, objective-c

What's the difference between a C# Interface and an Objective-C Protocol?  I ask because I'm diving into ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to grasp some of the new concepts and it will help if I can relate them to my Objective-C iOS programming background.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're basically the same. In Objective-C 2.0, though, you can mark some methods in a protocol as "optional" (using the `@optional` qualifier), which means that classes that implement the protocol aren't required to implement those methods.

Comment: If Objective C protocols are interfaces, then why separate interfaces In Objective C are necessary?

Comment: answer: the interface in Objective C is useless header file from C.