# Protocol vs Interface

Tags: c#, objective-c, syntax, swift

I've been reading the swift documentation, and working through the playground. I have to admit I have zero knowledge of Objective-C/iOS development (outside of Xamarin at least). To my eyes, a protocol seemed identical to the C# interface.

However, I noticed whilst looking around on the web that Objective-C has a concept of both a protocol ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679145/interface-and-protocol-explanation)) *and* an interface (although I'm not really sure what the difference is). Swift doesn't seem to have both - just protocols.

Could someone explain, for swift, what the difference/relationship between a Protocol and a C# interface is?

*Update:* I appreciate that the answer might be functionally the same as the duplicates listed, but I think that, given that this is asking about a *different language*, that the question still has merit in it's own right. After all, new developers to swift might have no knowledge of Java (beyond Javascript, I have none). Placing an expectation on someone to have knowledge of a totally different language system in order to have the answer to their question is a bit much, isn't it!? [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258363/old-question-new-technology-new-answer?cb=1) discussion on meta is also discussing this issue.

Comment: I realize it's about Java interfaces and not C# interfaces but the difference is so minor (Java-8 interfaces) that it should be the same.

Comment: A little late, but this one might be more appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824663/whats-the-difference-between-an-c-sharp-interface-and-an-objective-c-protocol?rq=1

Comment: Regarding your update, Java and JavaScript are utterly, entirely separate beasts. They have different origins, different paradigms, different features, and run in different environments. "Java is to JavaScript as Ham is to Hamster."

Comment: @Chris true, I was mostly indicating that my knowledge is non-existent for Java, so knowing that I could substitute C# for it would be impossible.

Comment: I agree totally with the "Update" added to the question. I find myself in similar situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Objective C protocols serve basically the same purpose as interfaces in Java/ C#. Objective C interface files are different. Like C, Objective C has interface files that publicly declare the methods and properties of a class, that are then implemented in an implementation file. For example you may have an interface file of a class that looks something like this:

```
@interface  
-(void)myMethod;
@end
```

then in your implementation file you actually implement the method:

```
-(void)myMethod{
    //code
}
```

Swift does away with separate interface and implementation files. So it only has protocols.